# jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler, Unrecognized cookie header 'set-cookie' in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Not able to login office 365 (https://office.com) using Jmeter tool

Error details in the log:

```
2018/02/12 15:47:43 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler: 
Unable to add the cookie org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: 
Unrecognized cookie header 'set-cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; 
secure; HttpOnly'
```

We have developed and integrated with 'One drive' excel and there is furthuer functionality after accessing One drive. We have to perform performance testing using Jmeter tool. Below steps followed:

1. Recorded the login https://office.com with our account flow using the Jmeter/Blazemeter tool> followed other functionality steps
2. Replied the recorded script in Jmeter 3.1>
3. Observed results> the results shows 'Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in' though just replayed the script immediately after recording.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType - Successful - able to get response

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login - Failed with 200 code (Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in) though used all recorded parameters.

The Login POST request has many cookies (set-cookies)

Below configuration/options are already tried:

Try out different "Cookie Policy" options
Set CookieManager.check.cookies=false in user.properties file
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.control=DEBUG

The log shows an error as pasted in the first section.
Please guide.

Comment: Can you try to execute it with latest JMeter version 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in [Http Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) the policy:

[image: Cookie Manager]

try different policies.

If it still fails, set Log Level to DEBUG:

[image: Log Level]

And run again the test, then make the log file available somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, able to overcome this issue. now no errors in the log, however the office.com has many cookies/dynamic values that goes along with the login request and do not know from where these values are coming/dynamic values (used debug sampler): list of dynamic values: the POST request is:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login
POST data:PPSX=&IsFidoSupported=0&ps=2&hisScaleUnit=&i13=0&login=test%40xyz.com&type=11&i17=&LoginOptions=3&flowToken=AQABAA&i19=16094&psRNGCEntropy=&i18=&loginfmt=test%40xyz.com&NewUser=1&canary=%2FyZhHA1&hisRegion=&ctx=rQ_5